# symfony conditionally set getParent in forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have created a symfony form type that decorated another type.
Now I want to apply exactly the same decoration to another type.

I was hoping I could set a parameter like $this->parent = ... from the config options but that does not work.

How can I change the parent of a form dynamically?

Comment: you can't do it after the form's been created, because the options are merged and resolved, among other reasons I think.

Comment: However you can return a different value for `getParent` each time, but you can't change after the form's been created.

Comment: what do you mean by 'decoration' of a form type?

Comment: What I am doing is displaying a select with an add button on its right. And I want to be able to choose the select type, ie choose the parent. I've resolved this by creating 2 different controls witch inheritate the same class with itself extends abstractType